# Pincushion and Perspective image corection

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I have to do the Perspective and barrel image correction using image magic. I can do this with convert command line tool. but i want to integrate with my c++ visual studio source. can I do this ?? please help me...

Comment: And what have you tried? How did your program work (or not work)? What can you show us? You *have* read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help)? You do know [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? And you do know how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `Magick::Image.distort` method to handle any perspective, or barrel, distortion. See [documents](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html) & [examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrel).

```cpp
Magick::Image image("wizard:");
double arguments[4] = {0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 1.5};
image.distort(Magick::BarrelDistortion, 4, arguments);
```

[image: Image Distortion]

```cpp
// Or perspective
Magick::Image image("wizard:");
double arguments[16] = {7, 40, 4, 30, 4, 124, 4, 123,
                       85, 122, 100, 123, 85, 2, 100, 30};
image.distort(Magick::PerspectiveDistortion, 16, arguments);
```

[image: Perspective Distort]

Comment: I have 6.9 imagemagick. but i not have lib dll and header file.. will you guide me to download correct windows 32 bit package...